# Drupal 8 separate domain for admin and web site

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I want to use separate domain names for drupal 8 admin CMS and front end.
I will be hosting my admin CMS in one instance and front end in another instance and would like to create different domains for each instance.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I have tried creating two instances pointing to common database and also tried Access Domain module. It is not working as per my requirement.